An American TV series about a group of young boys and girls
I watched this TV series in the late 80s or maybe the early 90s, it was subbed in Arabic and broadcasted on few middle eastern channels
Definitely it was American and it was not animated, I believe its from the same era of Small Wonder.
I don't remember that much about it but it involved a group of youth, they might have been family or friends. There was at least two girls and two boys.
In one the episodes, one of the young men gets hit on his head. He changes his haircut and starts dating girls. One of the girls in his household asks him something and he slaps her on her butt and she gets shocked. In another episode the same guy lends his credit card to one of his family and they abuse that and start ordering all they desire. Also in another episode he asks his friend or brother if they know the girl he is dating. His brother tells him that she has a birthmark on her thigh. Sadly that's all I can recall.

Which country did you see this in? Basing on "credit card" I'm assuming show was set in the late 80s.

I'm guessing this is a drama series and not comedy or other genres?

It is comedy indeed

Trying to work out if it's Boy Meets World.

Step by Step? There is an episode where one of the protagonist gets a cc and goes into a spending spree.

@AlasdairCM no it's not

@S182 not this one either

This might be Charles in Charge with Scott Baio. It ran from 1984-1990 and features at least 2 boys and 2 girls (the young Charles and the 3 kids he babysits). In one episode, he lends his credit card to one of the children; they go on a crazy shopping spree and later regret it. And in another couple of episodes (here's one of them), Charles bumps his head, slicks his hair back and transforms into a womanizing alter-ego called Chaz:

